# How to install dsfont package?

Tags: installing

Hi I tried to install the package by

```
tlmgr install dsfont
```

but I only get

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
package dsfont not present in package repository.
```

I also installed the package doublestroke since I read somewhere that this package contains dsfont, but if I include dsfont I still get an error message..

Does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: If you return one day, please specify what operating system you are working with and choose the according answer below.

Comment: How to install the `dsfont` package on Kile on Linux CentOS 7?

Answer (score 51):

On Debian based TeX distribution you can try

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Addendum: package [doublestroke](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/texlive-fonts-extra-doc/filelist) would be installed with this tweak which has `dsfont`

Comment: Does anyone know how I could have found this, sans Google?  `apt-cache search dsfont` didn't come up with anything.

Comment: @user1717828 I generally use an error message with double quotes around it. In this case it was: "! LaTeX Error: File `dsfont.sty' not found." from Anki. This was the top link.

Comment: I just need only this dsfont and I know that I can copy the sty file in my current folder. But is there any otherway? Because this causes 1,415 MB extra space.

Answer (score 29):

### TeX Live

The distribution package name is `doublestroke` in TeX Live for the LaTeX package `dsfont`.

From `tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb`:

> ```
> name doublestroke
> category Package
> revision 15878
> shortdesc Typeset mathematical double stroke symbols.
> longdesc A font based on Computer Modern Roman useful for typesetting
> longdesc the mathematical symbols for the natural numbers (N), whole
> longdesc numbers (Z), rational numbers (Q), real numbers (R) and complex
> longdesc numbers (C); coverage includes all Roman capital letters, '1',
> longdesc 'h' and 'k'. The font is available both as Metafont source and
> longdesc in Adobe Type 1 format, and LaTeX macros for its use are
> longdesc provided. The fonts appear in the blackboard bold sampler.
> execute addMap dstroke.map
> docfiles size=31
>  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/doublestroke/README details="Package Readme"
>  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/doublestroke/dsdoc.pdf details="Package documentation"
>  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/doublestroke/dsdoc.tex
> runfiles size=58
>  texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/doublestroke/dstroke.map
>  texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/doublestroke/dsrom.mf
>  texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/doublestroke/dsrom10.mf
>  texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/doublestroke/dsrom12.mf
>  texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/doublestroke/dsrom8.mf
>  texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/doublestroke/dsromo.mf
>  texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/doublestroke/dsromu.mf
>  texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/doublestroke/dsss10.mf
>  texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/doublestroke/dsss12.mf
>  texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/doublestroke/dsss8.mf
>  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/doublestroke/dsrom10.tfm
>  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/doublestroke/dsrom12.tfm
>  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/doublestroke/dsrom8.tfm
>  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/doublestroke/dsss10.tfm
>  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/doublestroke/dsss12.tfm
>  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/doublestroke/dsss8.tfm
>  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/doublestroke/dsrom10.pfb
>  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/doublestroke/dsrom12.pfb
>  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/doublestroke/dsrom8.pfb
>  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/doublestroke/dsss10.pfb
>  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/doublestroke/dsss12.pfb
>  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/doublestroke/dsss8.pfb
>  texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/Udsrom.fd
>  texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/Udsss.fd
>  texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/dsfont.sty
> catalogue-ctan /fonts/doublestroke
> catalogue-date 2012-04-25 18:00:26 +0200
> catalogue-license other-free
> catalogue-version 1.111
> ```

### MiKTeX

`doublestroke` is the distribution package name in MiKTeX for the LaTeX package `dsfont`.

Comment: very helpful! frantically & unsuccessfully searched in my MiKTeX for doublestroke

Comment: You should add how to install it from the command line.

Comment: What is the command line that you claim it contains?  I think `dsfont` is contained in `doublestroke`.

Comment: @relG  Yes, the LaTeX package `dsfont` is in the TeX Live distribution package `doublestroke`. The file name for a LaTeX packages is the package name with extension `.sty`. As you can see in my answer,  the file `texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/dsfont.sty` is part of `doublestroke`. Regarding the command line, I do not know your operating system, which TeX distribution is installed, and, in case of TeX Live, whether `tlmgr` is available (some Linux distributions omit it). Best, ask a new question with all the details and describe the problem you have.

Answer (score 3):

On Fedora 21:

```
yum install texlive-doublestroke.noarch
```