# Can't compile anymore after trying to install dsfont in MiKTeX 2.8

Tags: fonts, biblatex, installing, miktex

I'm currently writing my master thesis with MiKTeX 2.8. Now I wanted to install `dsfont`. But since 2.8 seems not to be supported anymore, I tried to install the package manually. I downloaded the `doublestroke` package, which contains `dsfont`, [here](http://ctan.org/pkg/doublestroke) and followed [these instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows):

- I already created the folder `C:\localtexmf` a few months ago
- I created a new folder `dsfont` in `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex`
- I put the `dsfont.sty` file into that folder
- In MiKTeX settings, I pressed the `refresh FNDB` and the `Update formats` buttons
- I loaded the package via `\usepackage{dsfont}` in my main file

That did not work. I got no error messages, but 81 warnings. Since I did not know why it didn't work, I also followed [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation) instructions:

- I executed `initexmf --edit-config-file=updmap.cfg`
- then I entered `# <font name> or <package name> or what fits better for you
  Map dsfont.map` into the file
- I executed `initexmf -u` as well as `initexmf --mkmaps`
- again, I pressed the `refresh FNDB` and the `Update formats` buttons

Still didn't work. Even worse, even if I don't try to load `dsfont` in my main file, the document is not compiled. That means that I can't keep working on my thesis even without using dsfont. The problem seems to be with BibTeX, because I get error messages from BibTeX:

> I found no `\citation` commands
>
> I found no `\bibdata`

Note that there is a folder for `biblatex` in the `localtexmf` folder: `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex`. But I'm not sure that I really needed that one for bibtex to work. Furthermore, since I got these problems, there is also a new file called `Masterarbeit.synctex(busy)` in my main folder (`Masterarbeit.tex` is my main document).

So, does anybody know how to make it work again? This is pretty important, because I don't have much time left and I don't want to risk to mess everything up with a new installation of MiKTeX. What did I do wrong during my installation of `dsfont`? Please help me!

EDIT: uploaded the log file from [Latex](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8368589/Masterarbeit.log.html) and also [bibtex](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8368605/Literatur.log.html)

UPDATE: Installed MikTeX 2.9 on a different PC, still the same errors/warnings. Something is wrong in the way I'm creating my Bib, but I don't know what since I did not change anything concerning my Bib.

Comment: Looks like everything is *already* messed up. It'll probably be quicker and easier to remove miktex 2.8 and do a clean install of miktex 2.9 and/or TeX Live 2013 (including `dsfont`). Perhaps somebody has a swift solution, but maybe you'd start the download in the meantime...

Comment: The bibtex messages are warnings not errors. Without more informations egg log-files, it is not possible to say what wrong

Comment: I added the log files, but I'm not sure if they help. I can't find the warnings from bibtex which I described above in there. Sorry, I am not a great expert. Do you know in which file they could be?

Comment: If you have internet, download MiKTeX version 2.9 and install it and update. This would be the easy way out. Did you run `updmap`?

Comment: Yes, I executed that as well. I also forgot to mention that after I got these problems, I first deleted the text in the updmap.cfg file and executed the "initexmf -u" and the "initexmf --mkmaps" commands. Because that didn't help either, I simply deleted the updmap.cfg file.

Comment: Seems that I will have to install 2.9 I tried to avoid that since I'm not sure if I'm not getting even more trouble when I try to use my "old" files with the new installation.

Comment: I can't access the files you uploaded. I can't see the links.

Comment: Hm, strange. Works for me, others also have already downloaded them. Maybe if you try another browser? Anyway, I'm going to install MikTex 2.9 on another PC and see if I can compile my thesis there. But I thank you and all the others for your help.

Comment: Curiously now the image appeared. Your masterarbeit.log stops in the middle which means that you either killed the process instead of ending is correctly or that something blocked the on-the-fly installation (you should disable it anyway). Also you seem to use pdflatex but load psfrags which is rather dubious. Your literatur.log shows that you are trying to compile a .bib-file and that this .bib-file contains \chapter-commands. Both is simply wrong.

Comment: I have to admit, I don't really know how I'm creating my bibliography right now. I am using natdin as style file. Both natdin and natbib are in my main folder. In the header of my main file, I'm loading natbib via "\usepackage[square]{natbib}" and setting the bibstyle via "\bibliographystyle{natdin}". But I did not change anything concerning these files. Something is completely wrong though, because after I installed MikTeX 2.9 on a different PC, I get the same warnings/erros.

Comment: I also can't find the log-file for BibTex anywhere. The one I posted does not show the errors/warnings that I'm getting from BibTex.

Comment: You need someone which can look at your system and sort it out.

Comment: BTW: Cf. [How to install dsfont package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96873/how-to-install-dsfont-package) No need for manual installation in MiKTeX: Go into the Package Manager and install package `dstroke` (nethertheless you have to invoke it with `\usepackage{dsfont}`).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because according to comments it seems to be caused by a fundamental problem of OP's operating system.