# Linux CentOS 7, LaTeX issue on Kile: File 'dsfont.sty' not found

Tags: fonts, texlive, linux, kile, centos

I'm trying to compile a LaTeX file with Kile on a laptop running Linux CentOS 7.

In the .tex file, I've the command `\usepackage{dsfont}`
Kile does not compile my file and produces the following error:

`File 'dsfont.sty'  not found`

What can I do to solve this problem?

I tried to install all the texlive packages with this command, but it did not solve the problem:

`sudo yum -y install texlive texlive-*.noarch`

Edit: Ralf Stubner pointed out that there's [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96873/how-to-install-dsfont-package) explaining what to do. I checked it but unfortunately it does not solve my problem and it does not provide solutions for Linux CentOS.

Comment: @RalfStubner That answer does not provide instructions for Linux CentOS 7 unfortunately

Comment: https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=60137

Comment: Have you tried the solution for Fedora together with the EPEL repository, i.e. after ‚yum install epel-release‘?

Comment: What do you mean? I just tried `sudo yum -y install epel-release` and `sudo yum -y install texlive-doublestroke.noarch` and the problem is still there.

Comment: That is what I meant. What was the output of these commands?

Comment: `Package epel-release-7-11.noarch already installed and latest version` and `No package texlive-doublestroke.noarch available.
Error: Nothing to do`. Any idea? Thanks