# Unable to install TeX package in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, ubuntu, miktex2.9

I am using Pop!_os 18.04 LTS (which is based on Ubuntu 18.04) and I am trying to get program to run which makes heavy use of LaTeX. I am using the MiKTeX package manager to install the TeX packages that the program requires. I am stuck on trying to get this package `dsfont` to install. According to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96873/how-to-install-dsfont-package) answer, installing texlive-fonts-extra should have fixed it. I tried using `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` and it installs correctly but the error still stands.

The same thread also explains how `dstroke` is the distribution package name in MiKTeX for `dsfont`. However, I cannot find a package named `dstroke` in MiKTeX. The search returns an empty list. The had suggested that a package named `doublestroke` was being used in TeX live for getting `dstroke`. So I tried searching for that in MiKTeX just in case and I was able to find it and install it. But that also did not fix the error. I cannot find any other pointer to installing this. Please help.

```
OS: Pop!_OS 18.04 (Similar to Ubuntu 18.04)
Python: 3.7.1
MiKTeX: MiKTeX Package Manager 2.9.7043 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050)
```

TeX error Log -

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050) (preloaded format=latex 2019.7.21)  21 JUL 2019 22:41
entering extended mode
**./media/Tex/f4fdd6aabf2e43a0.tex
(media/Tex/f4fdd6aabf2e43a0.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/home/ana
nda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count80
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count81
\c@sapage=\count82
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
) (/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count83
\c@section=\count84
\c@subsection=\count85
\c@subsubsection=\count86
\c@paragraph=\count87
\c@subparagraph=\count88
\c@figure=\count89
\c@table=\count90
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/preview/preview.sty
Package: preview 2017/04/24 11.91 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/preview/prtightpage.def
\PreviewBorder=\dimen103
)
\pr@snippet=\count91
\pr@box=\box27
\pr@output=\toks16
)) (/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2019/07/19 3.33 The Babel package
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2019/07/19 3.33 Babel switching mechanism
) (/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2019/07/19 3.33 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count92
\U@D=\dimen104
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count93
)
\l@british = a dialect from \language\l@english 
\l@UKenglish = a dialect from \language\l@english 
\l@american = a dialect from \language\l@english 
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)) (/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen105
)) (/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen106
) (/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count94
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 223.
\uproot@=\count95
\leftroot@=\count96
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 385.
\classnum@=\count97
\DOTSCASE@=\count98
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 482.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 485.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 606.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box28
\strutbox@=\box29
\big@size=\dimen107
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 729.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 730.
\macc@depth=\count99
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count100
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count101
\dspbrk@lvl=\count102
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count103
\column@=\count104
\maxfields@=\count105
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen108
\alignsep@=\dimen109
\tagshift@=\dimen110
\tagwidth@=\dimen111
\totwidth@=\dimen112
\lineht@=\dimen113
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2844.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2845.
) (/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(/home/ananda/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))

! LaTeX Error: File `dsfont.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.7 \usepackage
               {setspace}

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2175 strings out of 494858
 28788 string characters out of 3178198
 96215 words of memory out of 3000000
 5854 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,0n,56p,244b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

No pages of output.
```

Comment: The package `dsfont.sty` is available as `doublestroke` in both MikTeX and TeX live  (see https://ctan.org/pkg/doublestroke). Did you try installing that package via the MikTeX Console? You may want to remove `texlive-fonts-extra` and other packages that `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` may have installed, since this probably installed another (possibly outdated) TeX live from the Ubuntu repositories on your system.

Answer (score 1):

As a MiKTeX package it is known as *doublestroke*. Furthermore, it may happen that you have to launch `updmap` to refresh the type 1 fonts database:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that do not install TeXLive from Ubuntu repository. Get latest TexLive 2019 from [CTAN repository](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and install it. First remove previous installed packages and MikTex.

```
‫sudo apt-get remove texlive-*
```

Go to the folder which you downloaded, and run the following command:

```
sudo perl install-tl --gui=perltk
```

Comment: The OP has already installed MikTeX for Linux. Installing another TeX system (vanilla TeX live) might cause more confusion than it does good.

Comment: @moewe Yes, you are right. But it could cause more problems later. It is better to remove all texlive compiler and install complete CTAN Texlive.

Comment: I agree that removing the TeX live that was (inadvertently) installed by `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` is probably a good idea, but I don't necessarily agree that the OP should install vanilla TeX live when they already have access to a reasonably up-to-date (and updatable!) MikTeX. The solution here would probably involved installing the package in MikTeX rather than demolishing everything and switching the TeX distribution.

Comment: But I think that the problem has raised is that the ANANDA tex editor uses MikTeX compiler, not the compiler which installed using 'sudo apt'. So installing texlive-fonts-extra does not help. As you suggested one way is to install some necessary packages using MikTeX package manager.

Comment: As I wrote in my comment above I agree with that part of the analysis. But I disagree that the best course of action given the status quo is to remove MikTeX and install vanilla TeX live. Installing the correct package in MikTeX should be enough.